# hacer Strcpy o una copia hacia un puntero doble con los datos de un tipo String

Tags: c++, string

Hola tengo el problema que me han dejado realizar una pequeña modificación a un código pero esta me decía que solo sustituyera las variables de tipo `char *` y ponerla en tipo `string`. El problema es que en una parte del código éste usa 
`char **` y éste intenta hacer una copia con `strcpy` para que los `char **` tengan la misma información de los que ahora son tipo `string`.

El problema es más que todo de sintaxis ya que no se cómo podría solucionar este problema sin modificar los que actualmente siguen siendo `char **` y seguir usando `string` en los que antes eran `char *` y sí, he problado a hacerlo como si de una cadena `string` se tratase (`string=string`), pero no funciona.

Dejaré el código del las libreria de mi clase y  de donde se encuentra el problema.

```
#ifndef _PARTICIPANTE_H_
#define _PARTICIPANTE_H_
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class CParticipante {
private: //Datos miembros
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    char sexo; //masculino o femenino
    string lugar_nacimiento; //ciudad y pais
    string pais_residencia;
    string doc_identidad; //cedula, carnet, pasaporte
    string telefono; //(505)311-4012
    string e_mail;

public:
    //funciones miembros publicas
    CParticipante();
    CParticipante(string, string, char, string, string, string, string, string);
    ~CParticipante();
    CParticipante(const CParticipante&);
    CParticipante& operator=(const CParticipante&);
    void SetParticipante(string, string, char, string, string, string, string, string);
    //recibe 8 parametros y los almacena en las variables correspondientes
    //al objeto que recibe el mensaje
    void GetParticipante(char**, char**, string, char**, char**, char**, char**, char**) const;
    //obtener un participante, permite el acceso a los datos del objeto que recibe el mensaje
};

bool Verificar_Documento(string); //verifica si el doc_identidad es correcto

bool Verificar_Telefono(string); //verifica si el telefono es correcto

bool Verificar_Correo(string); //verifica si el correo es correcto

void EscribirParticipante(const CParticipante&);

int Menu();

#endif

void CParticipante::GetParticipante(char** nom, char** apell, string sex, char** lugar, char** pais, char** doc, char** tel, char** correo) const
{
    //Asignar memoria a los datos a retornar
    *nom = new char[nombre.length() + 1];
    *apell = new char[apellido.length() + 1];
    *lugar = new char[lugar_nacimiento.length() + 1];
    *pais = new char[pais_residencia.length() + 1];
    *doc = new char[doc_identidad.length() + 1];
    *correo = new char[e_mail.length() + 1];
    *tel = new char[telefono.length() + 1];

    //Copiar los valores de los datos miembros del objeto a las variables a retornar

    strcpy(*nom, nombre);

    strcpy(*apell, apellido);

    sex = sexo;

    strcpy(*lugar, lugar_nacimiento);

    strcpy(*pais, pais_residencia);

    strcpy(*doc, doc_identidad);

    strcpy(*tel, telefono);

    strcpy(*correo, e_mail);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si realmente quieres copiar en una formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres el contenido de un `std::string`, debes cambiar tus llamadas a `strcopy` así:

```
strcpy(*nom, nombre.c_str());
//                  ^^^^^^ <-- Obtiene el puntero interno del std::string
```

Pero esa no es la manera C++ de trabajar, deberías usar `std::copy`

```
std::copy(nombre.begin(), nombre.end(), nom);
```

Pero ni siquiera esa es la mejor manera de trabajar en C++, aunque sea más correcta. Lo que deberías hacer es cambiar tu función `GetParticipante`. Al tener como nombre `Get`, lo esperable es que devuelva un valor, así pues si creamos un objeto que almacene valores de participantes:

```
struct Participante {
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    char sexo; //masculino o femenino
    string lugar_nacimiento; //ciudad y pais
    string pais_residencia;
    string doc_identidad; //cedula, carnet, pasaporte
    string telefono; //(505)311-4012
    string e_mail;
};
```

Podemos devolver directamente los datos:

```
Participante CParticipante::GetParticipante() {
    return {
        nombre,
        apellido,
        sexo,
        lugar_nacimiento,
        pais_residencia,
        doc_identidad,
        telefono,
        e_mail
    };
}
```

Puedes usarlo así:

```
CParticipante p("John", "Doe", 'X', "Mordor", "Mordor", ":P", "666", "jd@mordor.net");
auto x = p.GetParticipante();
std::cout << "Hola " << x.nombre;
```

Comment: No veo demasiado sentido a que `CParticipante` devuelva un objeto de tipo `Participante` cuando claramente ambos objetos deberían ser equivalentes...

Comment: @eferion yo tampoco lo veo... pero el código está diseñado así, un objeto `CParticipante` al que se le piden todos sus datos en una sola llamada en lugar de individualmente ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯